# understanding the behavior of file upload form element

Tags: html, forms

I have this upload form

```
   <form id="upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


             <button id="sendata">snd data</button>    

        
        <div class="drop-zone">
            <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Drop file here or click to upload</span>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="drop-zone__input">
        </div>

    </form>
```

the button inside the form element is not attached to an event listener, but when i click it
a see a GET REQUEST performed
`"GET /?file= HTTP/1.1" 200` 

this GET Request overwrites my other GET Request
I solved the problem by deleating the button element from the form element, but can this
behavior be turned off ?

also what element causes this action the input element or the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button has by default the behavior of submitting.
[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

If you change your button to `<button type="button">Button</button>` it'll override the default submit behavior.